# React Router blank page between two different projects

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, react-router-dom

I've read some questions about it like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72309055/why-do-i-have-to-manually-refresh-the-page-for-the-component-to-load-when-using) but I could not fix my issue.

I have built the first project and I can navigate among its pages without problems. So I built another project and hosted it on a sub directory and when I try to navigate between the first project and the second one, I get a blank page. I have to refresh the page to make it work.

Is there a fix for this issue or do I have to attach the second project to the first one?

I also tried to remove the custom wrapper but it didn't work anyway.

I'm using `react-router-dom@6.4.0`.

First project router:

```
import { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

import { Home } from "./pages";
import { TravelDetails } from "./pages/TravelDetails";
import { Travels } from "./pages/Travels";

export function AppRoutes() {
    const Wrapper = ({ children }: any) => {
        const location = useLocation();

        useLayoutEffect(() => {
            document.documentElement.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
        }, [location.pathname]);

        return children;
    }

    return (
        <Router>
            <Wrapper>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/trips" element={<Travels />} />
                    <Route path="/trip-details/:id" element={<TravelDetails />} />
                </Routes>
            </Wrapper>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Second project router:

```
import { useLayoutEffect } from "react";
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route, Routes, Navigate, Outlet, useLocation } from "react-router-dom";

import { Home } from "./pages";
import { TravelDetails } from "./pages/TravelDetails";
import { Register } from "./pages/Register";
import { Travels } from "./pages/Travels";
import { Profile } from "./pages/Profile";
import { Terms } from "./pages/Terms";
import { IsAuthenticated } from "./auth";

export function AppRoutes() {
    const PrivateRoute = () => {

        return IsAuthenticated() ? <Outlet /> : <Navigate to="/dashboard" />;
    }

    const Wrapper = ({ children }: any) => {
        const location = useLocation();

        useLayoutEffect(() => {
            document.documentElement.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
        }, [location.pathname]);

        return children;
    }

    return (
        <Router>
            <Wrapper>
                <Routes>
                    <Route path="/dashboard" element={<Home />} />
                    <Route path="/dashboard/register" element={<Register />} />

                    <Route path="/" element={<PrivateRoute />}>
                        <Route path="/dashboard/home" element={<Travels />} />
                        <Route path="/dashboard/trip-details/:id" element={<TravelDetails />} />
                        <Route path="/dashboard/account" element={<Profile />} />
                    </Route>
                </Routes>
            </Wrapper>
        </Router>
    )
}
```

Firts project package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "website",
  "homepage": "https://mywebsite.com/",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
...
```

Second project package.json:

```json
{
  "name": "dashboard",
  "homepage": "https://mywebsite.com/dashboard",
  "private": true,
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "type": "module",
...
```

This is the way I try to navigate from the first one to the second one:

```js
const createAccount = () => {
    navigate("/dashboard/register");
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You effectively have two separate React apps running, one hosted/served from `"/"` of `"https://mywebsite.com"` and the other hosted/served from `"/dashboard"` of `"https://mywebsite.com"`. React-Router only handles ***internal*** navigation and routing within itself, so if you want to navigate from one app to the other you'll need to use regular HTML anchor tags for declarative navigation, e.g. `<a href="https://mywebsite.com/dashboard/register">Register</a>`, or in the cases of imperative navigation use `window.location.href` or `window.open`.

Example:

```js
const createAccount = () => {
  window.location.href = "/dashboard/register";
};
```

Since the second app is hosted/served from a sub-directory you'll likely also want to set the [`basename`](https://reactrouter.com/en/main/router-components/browser-router#basename) prop on the router so all routing/navigation is relative to *that* sub-route.

Example:

```
...
import {
  BrowserRouter as Router,
  Route,
  Routes,
  Navigate,
  Outlet,
  useLocation
} from "react-router-dom";
...

const PrivateRoute = () => {
  return IsAuthenticated()
    ? <Outlet />
    : <Navigate to="/dashboard" replace />;
};

const Wrapper = () => {
  const location = useLocation();

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    document.documentElement.scrollTo({ top: 0, left: 0, behavior: 'smooth' });
  }, [location.pathname]);

  return <Outlet />;
}

export function AppRoutes() {
  return (
    <Router basename="/dashboard">
      <Routes>
        <Route element={<Wrapper />}>
          <Route path="/" element={<Home />} />
          <Route path="/register" element={<Register />} />
          <Route element={<PrivateRoute />}>
            <Route path="/home" element={<Travels />} />
            <Route path="/trip-details/:id" element={<TravelDetails />} />
            <Route path="/account" element={<Profile />} />
          </Route>
        </Routes>
      </Route>
    </Router>
  );
}
```

Though unrelated to the routing/navigation question, I want to also point out that it's a general React anti-pattern to declare React components inside other React components as they will be redeclared any time the parent component rerenders which can lead to unexpected side-effects and issues. I've moved the `PrivateRoute` and `Wrapper` component outside of `AppRoutes`.